# Receive JSON string from client and directly convert it to JSON object and save on server?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I wanna speed up the process of saving (developement time) some objects on Parse and wonder if the following is possible:

I have an object called `TestObject` with the columns: `testCol1, testCol2 ... testCol9`. If I wanted to save an object of this kind and the client has to send a value for all these columns the code on the server (cloud-code) would be quite messy (unnecessary long). Example:

```
var col1 = request.params.col1;
var col2 = request.params.col2;
...
var col9 = request.params.col9;
```

And then when setting the these values on the actual object the process has to be kinda repeated. Is there a way I can do something like:

```
var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
var testObject = new TestObject(JSON.stringify(request.params));
testObject.save();
```

Comment: Any reason why you use Cloud Code in addition to the saving logic the SDK already implements?

Comment: I wanna keep all the logic on the server and make REST-calls to the server to keep the client-side simple. Maybe I should have mentioned that I use the REST-api? Is what I'm asking possible?